# Why is page refresh triggering .keyup()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
$('.PhoneNumbers').on('keyup focusout', $('input:text[name^="Customers[0].PhoneNumbers"]'), function (e) {
    phoneRadioBtns(e);
});
```

The problem is that when I refresh the page it triggers the keyup event and it executes the function, which is not the desired result.  Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: Is this code inside a $document).ready() block?  Are you sure it's keyup and not focusout?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure its keyup bc when I only use focusout it does not fire when the page is refreshed (when the page loads). But I want the result to also happen on keyup not only focusout. . .

Comment: No it is not in the document ready, it's inside of a function.

Comment: Though, the function that it is inside of gets called in the document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it happen only when you press F5 while inside the input?

(This was the only way I managed to reproduce: try here http://jsfiddle.net/ybuTv/)

One way of solving it is to exclude the F5 button from the event: http://jsfiddle.net/ybuTv/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('.PhoneNumbers').on('keyup focusout', $('input:text[name^="Customers[0].PhoneNumbers"]'), function(e) {
        if(e.which!=116){
            phoneRadioBtns(e);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I just tried the F5 inside the input versus outside of it (in my app) and it doesn't matter.  I guess its not the refresh that triggering it, its the page loading that triggers the keyup.

Comment: Did you try not using keyboard at all and just the mouse and got the same result? do you have anyhere in the code xxx.keyup() or xxx.focusout()

Comment: It happens when I hit the refresh symbol on the browser too.

Comment: Yes, I tried just using the mouse not the keyboard but it still happens.  I just checked and there are other .keyup() in the code!  And one of them is hitting my break point so I guess its getting called. . . but its not entering any characters into the input so I don't know how its affecting it

Comment: Oh maybe this is it:

    $('input.phoneNumber', selectorContext).trigger('keyup');

Would that automatically fire all keyups?